# Can we make object of subclass and call parent class method?

Tags: java

```
public class polymorphism {
    public void show()
    {
        System.out.println();
    }

    public void show(int i)
    {
        System.out.println("6");
    }

    public class B extends polymorphism 
    {

    } 

    /** * @param args the command line arguments */ 
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    { 
        // TODO code application logic here B obj=new B(); obj.show();
    }
}
```

Comment: Especially the second answer from that duplicated question is what you are looking for. Hint: class names start Uppercase in Java. Always.

Answer (score 0):

To call a method in an object's parent class, you can use the 'super' keyword.

Ex. super.show();